# 'predict' using rules created by apriori [r]

Tags: r, apriori

I'm using apriori function to create an item recommendation system. I've successfully created rules using:

```
tr <- read.transactions("itemList.csv", format = 'basket', sep=',')
rules <- apriori(tr, parameter = list(supp=0.01, conf=0.8))
rules <- sort(rules, by='confidence', decreasing = TRUE)
```

one of the rules is  {eggs} => {milk}

now I want some kind of functions that prints *milk* if I put in *eggs*.

```
> function(rules,'eggs')

     'milk'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `recommenderlab` can produce recommendations based on association rules mined with `arules`.

Comment: Michael is right about recommenderlab, although it doesn't make use of the apriori function.